# create arrays error 500

Tags: php, arrays

i don't understand, when i create an array in my file.php, it's not working. I have only this code in my page:

```
$organization = array(
    'name' => '- offre',
​
​
);
var_dump($organization)
```

and it made me an error 500.
I made phpinfo() to see my php version and i have 
PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze3
Do you have an idea where this error come from ?
when i declare variable it works but it can't read only array. I have made a script without array it works but when i am using arrays i get error 500.

Comment: `var_dump($organization)` semicolan miss ?

Comment: remove comma after offre.?

Comment: I don't get any problem. [https://3v4l.org/WH8XG](https://3v4l.org/WH8XG). This is the output for _Output for 5.5.0 - 5.6.21, hhvm-3.9.1 - 3.12.0, 7.0.0 - 7.0.6_, At first search why the `500` shows.

Comment: remove comma from array. Add semicolon on var_dump. And turn errors from php.ini. I think that the reason why you get 500 error is that you have turned off the errors. 
check this: ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: @sAcH, You can't change the original post.

Answer (score 2):

just delete the comma

```
$organization = array(
    'name' => '- offre'
);
```

add semicolon after **var_dump**

```
var_dump($organization);
```

Comment: you should need some more description about what you did

Comment: i put the coma in my file but it's not working i didn t copy/paste well my code...

Comment: @ibrahimmohho, This is good, But without the description the answer is bad.

Comment: this is my first answer in stackoverflow :)  , thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Internal Error 500**

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Solution:**

In PHP each and every statement end with a semicolon `;`, and in your code you miss it, so the problems comes out. So use the `;` after the `var_dump`. Remove white spaces from the array.

[Check online](https://3v4l.org/aD66G), Mush check it.

```
$organization = array(
    'name' => '- offre',
);
var_dump($organization);
```

> Note: Without the `;` you will be notified `Parse error: syntax error,
>   unexpected end of file ... At line ..`

Comment: i add this in my php file ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL)  but it display nothing for me

Comment: 500 is a internal server error, not for the missing of semicolon, But that might be another reason. Without semi colon it just gives a syntax error.

Comment: in my real file i add the semicolon(wrong copy/paste in stackoverflow) and still not working, Frayne Konok is right ! the error is not from the semicolon

Comment: yeah i copy colle your code but still not working i thing it s not an error from my code, i keep you in touch when i figure it out

Comment: Check out the whole page, may be some where else creating the problem.